# EntityQuery condition for multivalue fields

Tags: 8

I need to select some entities that have a certain field (user reference) empty or that field does not contain the current user as a reference.

I tried this. It works fine if the field is empty or if the field contains exactly one value. For multiple values, it displays the wrong value.

```php
$query = $this->entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('my_entity_type')->getQuery();
$group = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->notExists("my_field")
  ->condition("my_field", \Drupal::currentUser()->id(), "<>");
$query->condition($group);
$query->condition("type", "my_bundle_id");
```

What changes should I do to my code to make it work with a multi-value field?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT IN` instead of `<>`.

```php
$query = $this->entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('my_entity_type')
  ->getQuery();
$group = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->notExists("my_field")
  ->condition("my_field", \Drupal::currentUser()->id(), "<>");
$query->condition($group);
$query->condition("type", "my_bundle_id");
```